# Can the Host Header be different from the URL

Tags: wcf, http, proxy

We run a website which is hosted using WCF. 
The website is hosted on: https://foo.com and the ssl certicate is registered using the following command:

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=foo.com:443
```

When we browse the website on the server, all is fine, and the certificate is valid.

There is a loadbalance in front of the server which listens to bar.com and then redirects the request to our server. 
The loadbalancer doesn't rewrite the get URL, but only the Host Header.

The rewritten header looks like this:

```
GET https://foo.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: bar.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

Now we have some issues which indicates that the ssl certificate is invalid in this case.

The Loadbalancer itself has a certificate registered listening to https://bar.com

Questions:

- Is it ok/allowed that the get URL and the Host in the http header are different?
- If it is ok to have different values in the header, under which url should we run the site? get URL or Host url?

Comment: Umm, which connections are SSL? Client->LB, LB->server? Does the LB have its own certificate? If yes, what is its CN?

Comment: The Loadbalancer itself has a certificate registered listening to https://bar.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, referencing the RFC2616:

> If Request-URI is an absolute URI, the host is part of the
>   Request-URI. Any Host header field value in the request MUST be
>   ignored.

So, back to your questions:
It is allowed but a bad idea as it will create confusion, better to use relative path. i.e.

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
```

instead of

```
GET https://foo.com/path HTTP/1.1.
```

Modify the loadbalance configuration to do so. Or make the both values the same.

If Host header has a value different than the request URI, then the URI is taking priority over the Hosts header.

Comment: This might be the issue. I'm now in touch with the DevOps which are responsible for the network/loadbalancer. I'll add an answer/mark as answer asap